# System.Data.EntityException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, azure

I have little experience with C#, ASP, .NET, Visual Studio, or Azure.  I have a web application that is performing fine when deployed to Azure (I still don't understand this process), but when I run Debug -> Start Debugging in Visual Studio 2012, I get this error:

```
System.Data.EntityException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=The underlying provider failed on Open.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
       at Awesomeness.Core.BaseController.AddLog(String key, String message) in c:\Users\zack\Code\Awesomeness Reminders\AwesomenessWeb\AwesomenessWeb\Core\BaseController.cs:line 76
       at Awesomeness.Core.BaseController.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) in c:\Users\zack\Code\Awesomeness Reminders\AwesomenessWeb\AwesomenessWeb\Core\BaseController.cs:line 26
       at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
  InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
       HResult=-2146232060
       Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
       Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
       ErrorCode=-2146232060
       Class=20
       LineNumber=0
       Number=2
       Server=""
       State=0
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
            at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
       InnerException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
            HResult=-2147467259
            Message=The system cannot find the file specified
            ErrorCode=-2147467259
            NativeErrorCode=2
            InnerException:
```

I would appreciate tips on how to sort it out as well as suggestions for essential background reading.

Thank you.

EDIT:

My connection string, in Web.config, is:

```
    <!-- local -->
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Awesomeness.csdl|res://*/Models.Awesomeness.ssdl|res://*/Models.Awesomeness.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Awesomeness;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, in the web configuration file, from the `ConnectionString`, I removed

```
 integrated security=True;
```

and it worked like a breeze!

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string in debug.

Comment: I updated my original post to include my connection string information.  What's the next step in the debug process?

Answer (score 0):

Click tools>connect to database.
Try to connect to the sql server database.
If you can't then that means it is not the connection string. I got this error

```
 "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server."
```

So you can search for that error, there is plenty of help for it online.

If you are able to connect to the database in Visual Studio then click on  the database and in the properties windows you will see the connection string. You can copy and past the connection string into your application, then you will know it is correct.